Dewalt charger: what is the purpose of zener diode in the primary side controller startup circuit
I've successfully converted two Dewalt battery chargers from 110V to 220V AC input. Success in my case means no smoke coming out and they do charge the batteries. I've got this by just replacing primary side caps. There's probably more to be done to ensure optimal operation.
Now I want to use this as a learning opportunity and at the same time make sure all important voltages remain within nominal ranges. On this path I came across a circuit which seems to have zener diode in series with the load, which I don't understand. The relevant part of the circuit is pretty much the same between my two chargers (DCB1104 and DCB1102), with some differences in resistors and caps values. Below, I'm taking all the values and markings from DCB1102 for my schematic for this question.
The primary side is built around OB2372 controller IC (datasheet). It has startup circuit composed of R1-R2-ZD5 which takes power from the input rectifier. There's another power source coming from the aux winding of the transformer. The aux winding power circuit makes total sense to me and my measurements match simulation pretty closely.
However the startup circuit has ZD5 in it (the part has ZK marking), which makes it different from the OB2372 datasheet reference schematics. There's also significant difference between measured and simulated voltages, further emphasising my lack of understanding of what is going on with ZD5.
What is the purpose/function of ZD5? Is it possible that ZD5 is not a zener diode but something else?
And how should I change parameters in order for circuit simulation to match measured VX voltage (30V vs 62V)?

update:
Adding a picture of the board as I might have missed something while capturing it into schematic. ZD5 can be found in the leftmost part of the board. Trace connecting it with Q2 emitter goes through TP54, under the controller IC, then under R7 and then connects to Q2.



Please post a link or image of the schematic you used to generate your simulation schematic, ie: Dewalt DCB1102. ||  2. Are you sure that Q5 in your simulation is an NPN BJT?  ||  3.  Is the voltage "Rectifier V1" really constant at 322V, or does it have some AC ripple?  || 4. Do you have scope waveforms for the voltages at the nodes you measured?  || 5. That link to the datasheet for OB2372 seems to be broken.


Tip: when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and then the Save and Insert button an editable schematic is added to your post.  No need for CircuitLab account, screengrab or image upload.

Well reverse engineering Dewalt is great public service

I would have expected ZD5 to be in parallel with C12. If you flip the Q2 to horizontal (and it’s probably reversed), I would expect it to form a Zener-NPN linear regulator. If your SMPS IC in parallel to C13?

@FabioBarone thank you for helpful questions & comments. 1. Picture added. I can annotate components and traces if necessary, but wanted to give clear view of the board first. || 2. I'm pretty sure Q2 is NPN, it aligns with my measurements; its marking is M4A which points to MMBT4401 NPN general purpose switching transistor.  || 3. You're correct, it should have some AC ripple, as it comes right after rectifier, inductance and smoothing capacitors. || 4. I don't have waveforms at the moment but I can try capture those. || 5. Added another link to the datasheet.

@winny re: ZD5 parallel to C12: I agree that it would make more sense but ZD5 is not connected to ground. re Q2: My understanding is that Q2 takes reference voltage from ZD4 in order to make 15V for the controller IC from aux winding voltage which varies widely depending on load (I saw 15-30V in my measurements).

Interesting. Only reason I can think of is to impose an UVLO for the startup circuit.

Hmm, UVLO is an interesting vector. This circuit is designed for 110V so it would have something like 160V instead of 320V coming from the rectifier. And so it might have a shut off point which would be reasonable for under voltage condition.

Have you managed to identity the IC? Does it have any voltage sense or start-up sequencing or UVLO? What’s the voltage value on the Zener?

@SergeBalyuk  Continuing the questions/comments:  6.  Are the measured voltages taken with a DMM set to DC volts?  What is DMM reading for AC volts? || 7.  Are measured voltages taken with 230VAC applied, and the chip operating in run mode ie: after start-up via the R1, R2, ZD5, C12 network has been completed?

@SergeBalyuk  8. A single-shot capture of the start-up waveforms of voltages at the following nodes would be very informative:  V1, join of R1 & R2, ZD5 cathode,  ZD5 anode=Q2 emitter.
